# Getting invalid count in ZAP reports alerts

Tags: security, jenkins, owasp, zap

I integrated ZAP with Jenkins. If I scan my application I can see 4 alerts in console output, but in report it displaying alerts as 2.

I am not sure whether I am doing any mistake in this configuration.

If I do this manual scan using ZAP I can see more alerts. Please find the attached screenshots.

Jenkins console output:

```
[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SUMMARY... 
 ALERTS COUNT [ 4 ] 
 MESSAGES COUNT [ 3525 ]
 [ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SHUTDOWN [ START ]
```

Manual ZAP tool scan report

[image: Manual Scan report]

Jenkins scan report

[image: Jenkins Scan report]

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with version of the ZAP tool. In jenkins server i am installing 2.7.0 but in my local it is latest version i.e 2.9.0.
This the reason i am seeing alerts difffrence.